# Using Amazon SES & Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, amazon-ses

So I want devise to utilize amazon ses to send the "I forgot my password" emails to a user. I have followed all of the steps for setting up devise with Gmail and then tried to configure SES as the mailer in production.rb I am new with ruby and I am sure there is something I have done incorrectly with either my syntax or configuration.

Production.rb

```
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp,
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
      :user_name =>  ENV['AWS_SMTP_USER'], # Your SMTP user here.
      :password => ENV['AWS_SMTP_PASSWORD'], # Your SMTP password here.
      :authentication => :login,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I stored both AWS_SMTP_USER & AWS_SMTP_PASSWORD to the config using "$ Heroku Config"

Devise.rb

```
  config.mailer_sender = 'Admin@synapticecho.com'
```

I don't think I am missing anything else, but I haven't found anyone trying to use Devise & SES as the mailer. I'm just not sure what other pieces I might be missing and I didn't find the AWS documentation all that helpful for configuring SES to work with Devise.

*I can post the github project if it helps.*

Answer (score 1):

In my case.

I got the following error.

- `Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified`

but, just like you. I didn't know missing anything else.

try below setting.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: Rails.application.secrets.HOST }
config.after_initialize do
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries    = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:        Rails.application.secrets.ACTION_MAILER_ADDRESS,
    port:           Rails.application.secrets.ACTION_MAILER_PORT,
    domain:         Rails.application.secrets.ACTION_MAILER_DOMAIN,
    user_name:      Rails.application.secrets.ACTION_MAILER_USER_NAME,
    password:       Rails.application.secrets.ACTION_MAILER_PASSWORD,
    authentication: :login,
    ssl:            true,
    tls:            true,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

It works, my env.
That point is `config.after_initialize`.
but, I don't know why need it.

- Rails 4.1.4
- Devise 3.2.4
- AWS SES
- In AWS EC2
- Verified email's domain is 'gmail.com' ( I'll change it)

Comment: If you are running in sandbox mode and the email you are trying to SEND TO has NOT been verified it is going to block you from sending to that address with that specific error.
You basically have two options:
1) Use a domain you own to send and receive emails (you can verify an entire domain)
2)Add each account manually into the verified senders list until you can get approved for production mode (only send/receive to these accounts)

Comment: Did you put this code where I have my config.action_mailer code in production.rb?

Comment: Yes, I had verified my Domain and email. and, I make sure in production mode. so, try setting in production.rb. (I tried verified email. but, `Net::SMTPFatalError` occured. so, I add `config.after_initialize do` like above code. Then it works) sorry my english. (^ ^;)

Comment: I am hosting my application on Heroku  and it will not push from GitHub. I have replaced my production.rb code with yours just to see what happens and it tells me: `Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       SyntaxError: /tmp/build_c10e4311-ee0a-41a4-a5ce-d15ef7fbda34/config/environments/production.rb:119: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Comment: Sorry I found defference. Try in `application.rb`. In my env. It is be in application.rb. 

And I tried heroku. It is done without error.

Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compressing... done, 40.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v7
       http://.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by adding the following line in production.rb.

ActionMailer::Base.default :from => 'my.verified.email.address'